# Why does LINQ version of this foreach loop throw a NotSupportedException ("NotSupportedException")?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a line of LINQ code that throws a System.NotSupportedException.

```
        return unconvertedUrls
                   .Select(potentialQueryURL => ConvertPotentialQueryURLToSeed(potentialQueryURL))
                   .Where(id => id > 0)
                   .ToList();
```

The exception message is "Method 'Int32 ConvertPotentialQueryURLToSeed(SeedsSQLConnector.PotentialQueryURL)' has no supported translation to SQL"

However the simple conversion to a foreach loop runs with no problems.

```
        var result = new List<int>();
        foreach (var potentialQueryURL in unconvertedUrls)
        {
            var id = ConvertPotentialQueryURLToSeed(potentialQueryURL);
            if (id > 0)
            {
                result.Add(id);
            }
        }
        return result;
```

What's going wrong and why?

========== EDIT ==========

Odd, a colleague suggested another fix that works too. It looks like the LINQ was passing ConvertPotentialQueryURLToSeed to the database! Anyway here's the other fix, which is to add .ToList() to the previous statement:

```
        var unconvertedUrls = (from url in _DataContext.PotentialQueryURLs
                               where !convertedUrlIds.Contains(url.Id)
                               select url).ToList();
        return unconvertedUrls
                   .Select(potentialQueryURL => ConvertPotentialQueryURLToSeed(potentialQueryURL))
                   .Where(id => id > 0)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: I suspect you're using EF or NHibernate, the problem is the ORM can't translate what you have entered into SQL. What does your function do? Can you show us it? Your second example works because you aren't querying the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that LINQ to SQL doesn't execute that code of the query but tries to convert it to an SQL statement. As it doesn't know `ConvertPotentialQueryURLToSeed` this conversion failes.

The foreach works because in that case the method `ConvertPotentialQueryURLToSeed` is not used in the part of the LINQ query that is being translated to SQL.

The version with `ToList` works for the same reason: `ToList` fetches the data from the query so far from the database. From that point onward, you are working on normal C# objects aka LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll mark this as the answer in six minutes. Is there a way to tell LINQ that the function is a local and not a database one? Adding ToList() to the previous statement seems to do it (see edit to question) but is there a more readable way?

Comment: @dumbledad Your edit works because you have resolved the list using `ToList` and effectively performed LINQ on an in-memory collection in the second statement, so the second statement does not call the database.

Comment: @dumbledad: No, there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks again Daniel, I had mistakenly assumed that the behaviour of LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Objects would be much the same. I can see now that they aren't and that's something I'll need to be careful about.